# How to create a list of key:value pairs in a for loop?

Tags: python, dictionary, append, key-value

I have a for loop which outputs a list of 15 values:

```
for line in data: 
    line # type(line) is `<class 'list'>`
        # do things with line
```

This `line` is always a Python list of 11 values, i.e.

```
['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', ... ]
```

I have a list of dictionary keys, which I have manually created:

```
['key1', 'key2', 'key3', ...]
```

I would like to join my keys to each of the values for each line in my for loop. Therefore, I can define a new line that looks like

```
 ['key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3', ... ]
```

This would be used in the for loop, i.e.

```
for line in data: 
    line # values
    # join key-value pairs
    # new_line = ['key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3', ... ]
        # do things with new_line
```

EDIT: I don't believe this is a repeat question. `zip(keys, values)` does not produce the desired result.

EDIT2: Would it be easier to create one large dictionary within a list?

```
[{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3', ... }]
```

or perhaps a tab-delimited test file?

key1:value1  key2:value2  key3:value3   ....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you just want to make a dict from two lists, then use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function:

```
>>> keys, values = ['a', 'b'], [1, 2]
>>> list(zip(keys, values))
[('a', 1), ('b', 2)]

>>> dict(zip(keys, values))
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}

>>> [{k: v} for k, v in zip(keys, values)]
[{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}]

>>> ' '.join('{}:{}'.format(k, v) for k, v in zip(keys, values))
'a:1 b:2'

>>> '[{}]'.format(', '.join("'{}': '{}'".format(k, v) for k, v in zip(keys, values)))
"['a': '1', 'b': '2']"
```

Comment: So, it appears neither of the above options solves my problem. My output actually looks like 

    `['key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3', ... ]`.

Not `[('a', 1), ('b', 2)]` nor `{'a': 1, 'b': 2}`. It's a list of key-value pairs

Comment: @ShanZhengYang Do you want to get a list of dicts? `['key1': 'value1']` is not legal Python syntax.

Comment: I have quite a bit of data in the format  ['key1:value1',  'key2:value2',...] which which I was going to use partition(:), etc. I wanted the vectors above to be in the same format. It is possible to create one big dicitonary in a list, i.e. `[{'key1:value1',  'key2:value2',...}] `, or maybe even take the key-value pairs to make a tab-delimited text 

        `key1:value1   key2:value2    key3:value3 `...

Comment: @ShanZhengYang So you just want to make a string, not Python data structure?

Comment: That make be easier. (1) how to use key list and value list to make a key:value string (as in previous comment) and (2) how to turn a large dictionary in a list like `[{'key1:value1', 'key2:value2',...}]` into a key:value string?

Comment: @ShanZhengYang check out the latest update of the answer.

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm trying to parse this weird format so it is something standard. The last thing is I still have this:

`[{'key1:value1', 'key2:value2', 'key3:value3',...}]`

That's the only data I have, and it needs to be processed. I don't think this can be described as a Python data structure, but I need to parse this to become a string like 'a:1 b:2'. Is this doable?

Comment: @ShanZhengYang, that's a completely different question.

Comment: You're right---I'll ask in another thread. Thanks for the help!